# Embed video URL in Razor page MVC5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I am trying to embed video in web page using the URL of the video.
URL Will be Facebook video URL, Instagram video URL, YouTube video URL.
I am trying this code but it's return "www.facebook.com refused to connect."
,"www.youtube.com refused to connect."

```
 <iframe width="560"
                height="315"
                src="https://web.facebook.com/RoyaNews/videos/1512267332317362/?extid=xR0gOtJQ2S4PgSDW"
                frameborder="0"
                allowfullscreen>
            
        </iframe>
 <iframe width="560"
                height="315"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sb-f3xzLhpc"
                frameborder="0"
                allowfullscreen>
            
        </iframe>
```

[image: refused image]